# Meteor Oauth and Cordova Inappbrowser

Tags: cordova, meteor, facebook-login, google-signin

Can't seem to find an answer to this, i've looked everywhere. Currently in one of my **Meteor** apps i'm using loginWithFacebook and loginWithGoogle auth along with the ServiceConfiguration package. When the inappbrowser comes up to login a user in they are able to enter their credentials. However when they submit those creds the the inappbrowser white screens. The activity only occurs on the device, on the simulator the inappbrowser disappears and logs the user in. I've tried every solution including adding the cordova-inappbrower-plugin to my project and adding **loginStyle: 'popup'** to the ServiceConfiguration but nothing has work. If anyone know of why this might be happening please shed some light. I'm working on iOS9 for  both the simulator and the device.

Comment: Well I have the same issue using loginStyle : 'redirect' but sometimes it works in simulator and device . { iOS 9 / Android } .

Comment: @Hamza the problem ended up being the cordova pluggin itself. The current maintainer of the code don't allow the popup window to be disappear unless the user clicks done. I ended up getting around it by using one of the PR branches that solved the issue

Comment: @brain : in this case you may use loginStyle : redirect .

Comment: My issue variates between Meteor and App configuration at Facebook developer apps . 

what version of inappbrowser did you use ?

Comment: @brianScroggins what PR branch did you use to get this to work? Can you provide link?